# Creating dialog with knockoutjs components

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-components

I already use custom binding with knockout for displaying jqueryui dialog, but I would like to use knockout component feature.

So, I would like to write something like:

```
<window params="isVisible: isVisible">
    //there will be some html
</window>
```

And later somewhere in code:

```
self.isVisible(true); //That would open window
//or
self.isVisible(false); //That would close window
```

Problem is that I don't know how to apply $(element).dialog. When I register knockout component, I can only get container element of this component, but not injected element.

```
ko.components.register('window', {
        viewModel: {
            createViewModel: function(params, componentInfo) {
                // - 'params' is an object whose key/value pairs are the parameters
                //   passed from the component binding or custom element
                // - 'componentInfo.element' is the element the component is being
                //   injected into. When createViewModel is called, the template has
                //   already been injected into this element, but isn't yet bound.
                // - 'componentInfo.templateNodes' is an array containing any DOM
                //   nodes that have been supplied to the component. See below.

                // Return the desired view model instance, e.g.:
                return new MyViewModel(params);
            }
        },
        template: ...
    });
```

So, componentInfo.element is parent node, and if I apply dialog with $(componentInfo.element) I will set as dialog parent node, then my window tag would be:

```
<div><!-- Dialog will be applyed there-->
    <window params="isVisible: isVisible">
        //there will be some html
    </window>
</div>
```

I think it will work, but that extra div look unneeded here... Or this is the only way to do job done?

What is knockout.components way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement when I wanted to build a Knockout component for hosting a dialog window using Bootstrap v2 'modal' functionality. I used an observable boolean value in my page's viewModel, set to false initially. There isn't a simple way to communicate with components after they have been initialized, except by passing in observables via params.

This observable was passed as a param to a `<dialog-window>` component in the params, e.g.

```
<dialog-window params="visible: showDialog">[content]</dialog-window>
```

This then used a special binding handler for the 'modal' dialog, but in your case you could bind it direcly using a `data-bind='visible: YourParam'` attribute.

The main page could then simply call `showDialog(true)` to make the dialog visible.

Hope this helps.